# Afinal, Java é uma plataforma ou uma linguagem de programação?

Tags: java, terminologia

Vejo vários materiais referindo o Java como uma tecnologia (plataforma) e outros como uma linguagem de programação.

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/java/info

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ambos.

Existe a [linguagem de programação Java](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_(programming_language)) e uma plataforma que as pessoas chamam de Java também. Pode ser um pouco confuso, mas quase sempre a distinção não é importante. De qualquer forma eu acho melhor usar [Java platform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_(software_platform)) quando está falando da plataforma.

Plataforma não é necessariamente uma tecnologia, a plataforma é composta por várias tecnologias.

A linguagem de programação não deixa de ser uma tecnologia. Tecnologia é conhecimento, é ferramenta que usa um determinado conhecimento. A linguagem Java não é a única usada na plataforma Java.

Existe ainda uma VM chamada [Java Virtual Machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine) que faz parte da plataforma.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Também é uma ilha da Indonésia =D

Comment: Também é um café

Answer (score 6):

Uma boa analogia é comparar com o .NET da Microsoft. Quando se usa o .NET Framework pode-se programar em várias linguagens: C#, VB.NET, C++. Todas elas são compiladas para CIL (*Common Intermediate Language*) que é o código que efetivamente será executado na máquina virtual no .NET.

Em Java (falando da plataforma), pode-se programar também em várias linguagens, algumas delas são: Java, Groovy, Scala, JPython, Closure, etc. Todas essas linguagens são compiladas para *Bytecode* e, no final, serão executadas na mesma JVM (*Java Virtual Machine*).

Obviamente, os compiladores mudam pra cada linguagem, porém, como todas executam no mesmo ambiente (após compiladas), isso facilita (e muito) a interoperabilidade encontrada nesse tipo de solução.

Em Groovy pode-se utilizar de maneira transparente as bibliotecas escritas em Java. Da mesma forma, bibliotecas escritas em C# podem ser utilizadas em VB.NET.