# Como funciona a arquitetura do Flutter (Framework, SDK, Dart)?

Tags: dart, flutter

Nos estudos de Flutter muitas vezes fico confuso, ao criar uma UI, afinal estou utilizando Dart/Flutter (*framework*) ou ambos?

Ex:

```
children: widget.products.map((Product product) {
          return ShoppingListItem(
            product: product,
            inCart: _shoppingCart.contains(product),
            onCartChanged: _handleCartChanged,
          );
        }).toList(),
```

Como funciona a arquitetura do Flutter? Onde começa o Dart e termina o UI (*framework*) ou é tudo a mesma coisa?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dart é uma [linguagem de programação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/102452/101) então é composta por, supostamente, uma [especificação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/111284/101), um [compilador](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/104814/101), e uma [biblioteca](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/17501/101) padrão básica, além de um [*runtime*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/178596/101) que pode ser considerado parte dessa biblioteca ([mais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/51281/101)), ainda que tecnicamente seja outra coisa.

O Flutter é um *framework* (ou SDK, que seja), da Google também, para fazer aplicações, é algo completamente separado. Diz-se que o Flutter é um *killer application* do Dart porque esta linguagem foi criada há anos e ninguém deu bola pra ela, até porque ela não tem nenhuma grande melhoria em relação ao que já existia e tem defeitos, porém foi nela que escreveram este *framework* que várias pessoas gostaram, então ela começou ser usada. Quase tudo de sucesso no mundo corporativo acontece por motivos políticos e não pela qualidade técnica.

Obviamente que Flutter tem uma filosofia que se encaixa bem em Dart por razões óbvias. Muito do que você vai fazer no Flutter usará a infraestrutura fornecida pela linguagem de programação, incluindo a sintaxe e muitas funções da biblioteca básica como usou neste código. Mas a estrutura de dados em geral do que está usando e muitas funções são do Flutter. Pra isso tem que estudar profundamente a documentação das duas coisas e ver o que é de cada, por isso o ideal é aprender a linguagem sozinha e depois o *framework*, mas pelo que já vi isso não vai acontecer com quase todo mundo, e já prevejo problemas, será uma dessas tecnologias que as pessoas farão funcionar e não entenderão o que está fazendo (não por todos, claro).

Deve estar acontecendo o mesmo que aconteceu com jQuery, e acho que uma boa explicação é ver [a diferença do JavaScript para o jQuery](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/46983/101). Se entende essa diferença entende a diferença entre Dart e Flutter. Acho que a confusão será ainda maior porque praticamente ninguém usará Dart sem usar Flutter, pelas razões já citadas. Assim como não se programa em jQuery, não se programa em Flutter.

Bem a groso modo podemos comparar o Flutter com o Windows Forms do C#. Nunca fez parte do C#, ou mesmo da base do .NET especificado, fazia parte do produto empacotado pela Microsoft e muita gente achava que era tudo uma coisa só. Nem sei se isso ocorre de fato, eu sei que pode pegar o Dart sozinho, mas como quase todo mundo só quer saber do Flutter pega ele (o SDK) que já traz junto Dart (até onde eu sei) pra facilitar sua vida.

Eu já vi muita coisa por aí que confunde as duas coisas, isso não é bom sinal, mostra que a comunidade e até coisas oficiais são mal definidas e apesar de ser uma tecnologia "moderna" pode já ter começado com um caminho de gambiarras e displicências, o que nunca acaba bem como já vimos em diversas tecnologias, mas algumas tem a desculpa que foram criadas há mais de 25 anos atrás.

Pode estar ocorrendo [o mesmo que ocorre com Java](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/266489/101). Ou Ruby on Rails que as pessoas acham que é nele que elas programam e não em Ruby, outra linguagem que as pessoas praticamente só usam com uma tecnologia.

E tome cuidado com a documentação porque tende a ter exemplos de uso dos mecanismos da linguagem aplicando alguma coisa de Flutter, o que pode confundir. Os exemplos da documentação nunca são receitas de bolo para copiar e usar em seus códigos, eles estão ali para demonstrar o mecanismo, eles servem bem para isto, nada mais, e programar é aplicar o mecanismo aprendido, não usar algo pronto.

O maior motivo das pessoas usarem exceções do jeito errado é porque as documentações dão exemplos errados de uso, porque o objetivo ali não é mostrar o uso certo é mostrar outra coisa que por acaso tem uma exceção, aí eles tratam ela do jeito errado porque o foco não é esse, e as pessoas não entendem isso e copiam tudo errado. O mesmo ocorre com respostas mal formuladas no SO e outros sites, e quase todas são mal formuladas, a pessoa não está pensando em todos os cenários, não pensa na hora de responder que alguém vai ler aquilo e usar só copiando sem olhar todos aspectos. É um erro de atitude das pessoas. E isso parece estar fazendo as pessoas acharem que Dart e Flutter são a mesma coisa.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Dart/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Eu não referenciaria o Flutter como um 'framework', ele é mais que isso, um 'SDK' de desenvolvimento de aplicações multiplataforma.

Comment: Na página oficial ele diz que é menos que um framework, que é só um UI toolkit, na Wikipedia chama de framework, mas o que importa para as pessoas é ele ser algo pelo menos próximo de um framework, o fato de ter outras coisas e ser um SDK é circunstancial e paralelo, não o define de forma fundamental, eu já dei uma resposta sobre isso em https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/17552/101.

Comment: Em sua própria resposta que você linkou acima, se você conhecesse o flutter diria que é um SDK. Flutter disponibiliza um conjunto de ferramentas para a criação das aplicações, debugger, inspector, profiling (validações de performance), stack tracing de erros, entre outras. De fato algumas pessoas ainda se referem como framework, toolkit ou SDK, eu prefiro me referir sempre como um SDK. Claro que ele aproveita muito do SDK do Dart, mas ainda assim adiciona um ferramentário novo ao mesmo.

Comment: Os criadores se referem assim.

Comment: Nem sempre. Página oficial: https://flutter.dev/docs/resources/technical-overview . Parafraseando: 'Flutter is a mobile app SDK for building high-performance, high-fidelity, apps for iOS and Android, from a single codebase.'

Comment: Página oficial: https://flutter.dev/ o fato de cada lugar falar uma coisa diferente só depõe contra.

Answer (score 1):

O Flutter, como já citado, é um Framework feito a partir de uma linguagem, que é o Dart.
A grosso modo, Flutter está para o Dart, assim como:

- O Android está para o Java.
- O React está para o javascript.
- O Ruby on Rails está para o Ruby.
- O Django está para o Python.
- O Laravel está para o PHP.

Mas resumidamente, tudo que for Widget em seu código, se trata de Flutter.